# StringUtils.replaceEach that returns StringBuilder or StringBuffer?

Tags: java, apache-commons, stringbuilder, stringbuffer, apache-commons-lang

Is there a version of Apache's `StringUtils.replaceEach()` that returns a `StringBuilder` or `StringBuffer` instead of `String`?  I'd like to avoid copying code. If not, is there another library?

Comment: I would use indexOf and replace.

Comment: No StringUtils.replaceEach() will return only String not StringBuilder or StringBuffer,but you can use others.

Answer (score 0):

All of `StringUtils`'s methods return `String`s. You could, however, always do something like this:

```
StringBuilder builder = 
    new StringBuilder(StringUtils.replaceEach(myString, searchList, replaceList));
```